# JQuery autocomplete Postback not occuring on selection

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

I am using jquery AutoComplete in  my asp.net website. Autocomplete working fine but I want on any item selected or textchange it should postback but that is not happening. I need postback on selection because rest of other fields getting populated as per selected item. Below is my code.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="consigner" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:HiddenField ID="consignerId" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id$=consigner").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/book-online.aspx/GetConsigners") %>',
                    data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.split('-')[0],
                                val: item.split('-')[1]
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (e, i) {
                $("[id$=consignerID]").val(i.item.val);
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
    });  
</script>

[WebMethod()]
public static string[] GetConsigners(string prefix)
{
    List<string> myConsigner = new List<string>();
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection()) {
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString;
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand()) {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT clientID,clientName,City FROM clientsDetails WHERE (clientName LIKE @clientName) and status = 'active'";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientName", "%" + prefix + "%");
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            using (MySqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                while (sdr.Read()) {
                    myConsigner.Add(string.Format("{0}-{1}", sdr("clientName"), sdr("clientID")));
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    return myConsigner.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: you can try this events for selecting .`focusout() .change() .keypress()`

Comment: Is that server side events?

Comment: `TextChanged` event is their for server side for textbox

Comment: Can you tell me why it not getting text of selected item from autocomplete? I have implemented TextChanged event as well in codebehind. Now If I select any value from autocomplete it should hit to textchanged event initially. Please help yar